# Why won't the buttons show in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to place buttons on a chessboard, with the board being an image, but the queen, king and bishop buttons don't show. How would I fix this?

```py
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
root = Tk()
root.geometry("1200x1200")
img = Image.open("s8XND.png")

resized = img.resize((1200, 900), Image.ANTIALIAS)
chessboard = ImageTk.PhotoImage(resized)
canvas = Canvas(root, width = 1200, height = 900)
canvas.place( relheight = 1, relwidth = 1)
canvas.create_image(0, 0, image = chessboard, anchor = "new")

label = Label(root, bg = chessboard)
label.place(pady = 10, padx = 20)
#Black Rook
blackRook = Button(root, text = "Castle", fg = "white", bg = "black")
blackRook.grid(row = 1, column = 0)

#Black Knight
blackHorse = Button(root, text = "Horse", fg = "white", bg = "black")
blackHorse.grid(row = 1, column = 1)

#Black Bishop
blackBishop = Button(root, text = "Bishop", fg = "white", bg = "black")
blackHorse.grid(row = 1, column = 2)

#Black Queen
blackQueen= Button(root, text = "Queen", fg = "white", bg = "black")
blackQueen.grid(row = 1, column = 3)

#Black King
blackKing= Button(root, text = "King", fg = "white", bg = "black")
blackQueen.grid(row = 1, column = 4)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Your code cannot be executed due to errors: `_tkinter.TclError: bad anchor position "new"`.  Also you forgot to call `blackBishop.grid(...)` and `blackKing.grid(...)`.

Comment: Do you want to place the chessboard image inside the canvas or on the label? Because you are doing both at the moment. I suspect that you should be using canvas alone here and using `create_image` to draw the piece icons on the chessboard grid rather than using buttons. You can then detect which piece was clicked on using the canvas `.find_closest` method to detect which icon was clicked on.

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me. Note that I removed the Label and fixed several errors in your code:

```py
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
root = Tk()
root.geometry("1200x1200")
img = Image.open("s8XND.png")

resized = img.resize((1200, 900), Image.ANTIALIAS)
chessboard = ImageTk.PhotoImage(resized)
canvas = Canvas(root, width=1200, height=900)
canvas.place(relheight=1, relwidth=1)
canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=chessboard, anchor="nw")

# Black Rook
blackRook = Button(root, text="Castle", fg="white", bg="black")
blackRook.grid(row=1, column=0)

# Black Knight
blackHorse = Button(root, text="Horse", fg="white", bg="black")
blackHorse.grid(row=1, column=1)

# Black Bishop
blackBishop = Button(root, text="Bishop", fg="white", bg="black")
blackBishop.grid(row=1, column=2)

# Black Queen
blackQueen = Button(root, text="Queen", fg="white", bg="black")
blackQueen.grid(row=1, column=3)

# Black King
blackKing = Button(root, text="King", fg="white", bg="black")
blackKing.grid(row=1, column=4)

root.mainloop()
```

Also note that you made some copy-paste errors with `blackHorse` and `blackKing`.

Comment: Using `anchor="ne"` in `canvas.create_image(...)` will make the image not visible.   Use `anchor="nw"` instead.

Comment: Missed that. Fixed it. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks so much. Really appreciate it